# Efficient way to map devices to power outlets?

Tags: algorithm, automation

I have four [web power switches](http://www.digital-loggers.com/lpc.html) with eight remotely controllable power outlets each, for a total of 32 power outlets. I have a device under test connected to each outlet. These devices under test are networked and have SSH. They're designed to boot in under two minutes, but they occasionally take up to ten minutes to boot, due to being prototypes in development. They're also prone to randomly crashing, freezing, or otherwise becoming unresponsive.

I'm looking for a reliable, efficient, automated method of mapping devices to power outlets. My current method is reliable and automated, but it's pretty slow:

```
turn off all outlets
for each outlet:
    turn outlet on
    wait ten minutes
    try to connect to all devices
    store all responsive devices in a list
    turn the outlet off
    try to connect to the devices in the responsive list
    if any are no longer responsive, map them to this outlet
turn on all outlets
```

As you can calculate, this takes about ten minutes per outlet, and 10 minutes x 32 is 320 minutes, or over five hours. I feel like there has to be a better way, but I've been unable to come up with anything.

Comment: never have seen this device. Do you communicate to it via http requests? The online manual seems to only mention a web interface

Comment: I'm actually using a [Python module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlipower/) that handles the communications for me. But yes, you communicate using http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- this is an optimistic approach, the better your devices work, the faster and better it will work
- it's using the fact (as you state `I have a device under test connected to each outlet.`) that there is a 1:1 mapping of outlet vs device

This sequence essentially reverses yours because that way you just have to wait for 10 minutes (max) once - per cycle, see below.

```
turn on all outlets
wait for all devices to become active for up to ten minutes
   (but interrupt waiting once you see a number of devices corresponding 
    to the number of outlets turned on)
store responsive devices
for each outlet:
    turn outlet off
    try to connect to all devices remaining on the responsive list
    if any are no longer responsive, map them to this outlet
```

Quite probably you'll end up with a list of devices and outlets that's not mapped yet, so you can repeat this cycle with just the unmapped outlets until there are no outlets are left or until you run out of time.

So, in the very best case (all devices boot up correctly in the normal time) your test will be over in a bit over 2 minutes.

Comment: Your assumption of a 1:1 mapping is correct. I should be been more explicit about that. This does look like a good (and easy to implement) solution. I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Good luck - as explained above it's an optimistic approach, but I'm quite confident that in all but the most pathological cases it should offer a substantial time gain.  You could add an extra condition to the outer loop, eg give up after n cycles without a decrease of unmapped devices to avoid spinning around without any improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume outlets are numbered from 0 to 31.

first try: turn on all odd numbered outlets and note which devices are responsive

second try: turn on all outlets that have a 1 at the second place in the binary representation of their number (i.e. 2,3,6,7,10,11, ...)

third try: turn on all outlets that have a 1 at the third place in the binary representation of their number (i.e. 4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15, ...)

...

fifth try: turn on all outlets with numbers >=16

Now, every device was responsive in some of the tries. If you write the outcome again as a binary number, you get the number of the outlet.

For example, if a device was active in try 5, 3, 2 and inactive in 4 and 1, we get 10110 which is 22. So this this device must be connected to outlet 22.